# How do I enable a wrap on a large string variable in HTML?

Tags: html

I have a very simple subwindow that displays help text. I am giving it the data in a variable but the window expands horizontally instead of wrapping. So if the text is bigger than 20 characters or so, the window resizes. I do not want the window to resize, I want the text to break and fill in the box. In the style sheet, I have made it fixed at 150/150 but it seems to ignore that when running.

This is the HTML

```
<div style= "position: fixed; Top: 50px; right: 0px;" >
  <div class="legend-container">
    <div class="title">Legend</div>
    <div #graphOverviewComponentRef id="legend-overview-component"></div>
       <p style="font-size:11px; word-break: break-all; white-space: normal;">{{queryInfo}}</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

The variable (queryinfo) contains an explanation for the query and they are usually 100 characters or more. So if its displayed on one line,  its much wider than the window. I want the text to wrap and fill the box vertically.  This is my css

```
#legend-overview-component {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
```

Right now, the window is expanding horizontally even though I have fixed positioned it. So I end up with a single line running end to end on a screen.
Thoughts ?

Comment: One solution is that you edit your variable queryInfo so it has /n where you want the linebreaks and then use [innerHTML]="queryInfo" insted of using <p>{{queryInfo}}</p>

Comment: I have never tried that. But I will.

Comment: The writer liked that idea, but not seeing many concrete examples of that outside of JS. Do you know a website that explains its use well ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just need to put the `<p>` tag inside the div in question?

```
<div style= "position: fixed; Top: 50px; right: 0px;" >
  <div class="legend-container">
    <div class="title">Legend</div>
    <div #graphOverviewComponentRef id="legend-overview-component">
       <p style="font-size:11px; word-break: break-all; white-space: normal;">{{queryInfo}}</p>
    </div>
       
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Dang it. Yes, thank you. I missed that completely

Comment: sometime, all we need is a second set of eyes. happy coding